# JWT parse Token from the user that logged in in React App undefined property in json

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5.5

I used JWT for the React App to communicate securely with token authentication coming from the server. However when I try to retrieve it using postman. I got the error undefined property. Here is the code in my controller to verify the token session of the user using JWT and decode it to the controller in order to do some query and return it to the view.

```
try {

        if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
            return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
        }

        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

            return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());

        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

            return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());

        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

            return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());

        }

        // the token is valid and we have found the user via the sub claim
        $user = response()->json(compact(json_decode('user', true)));

        $patient = Patient::where('id', $user->id)->get()->first();
```

The JSON response is this.

```
 "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "some_name",
            "email": "some_email"
    },
```

Appreciate if someone can help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: add the endpoint with the controller method

Comment: This line is invalid `$user = response()->json(compact(json_decode('user', true)));`. Can you clarify what you expect that line of code to do? At this point you already have the user model.

Comment: I just added the compact to retrieve the user coming from the mobile verified by the JWT Route middleware. I just actually added the json_decode that is really invalid because I didn't knew how to do it. I need also to query the user from the patient model thats why I need the id inside the json format body encoded in. Btw I figure it out. I'll post the answer later.